Cannot infer argument or return type from callback dictionary without explicit generics
I store data in objects with different versions that use different keys and different types. The acceptable types for the data properties are defined in an interface that defines the versions as a dictionary type. I want to match the object with handler functions based on a matching key in the data. I create a dictionary value of handlers that stores the functions indexed by the associated key. I have  a generic handle function that takes one of the data objects, a dictionary of all handlers, and a callback that receives a matching value and handler function.
The flow works great if I provide explicit generics for the callback props other than the value and a separate generic for the result type. Without generics, the types are not inferred correctly and errors are thrown. How can I infer the type of those props and the callback result without needing to specific the generic values for each implementation?
export interface VersionDictionary {
  alpha: string
  beta: number
}
export type VersionKey = keyof VersionDictionary
export type Handler<Key extends VersionKey, OtherProps, Result> = (props: OtherProps & {
  value: VersionDictionary[Key]
}) => Result
export type Handlers<OtherProps, Result> = { [Key in VersionKey]: Handler<Key, OtherProps, Result> }
export interface Matched<Key extends VersionKey, OtherProps, Result> {
  handler: Handler<Key, OtherProps, Result>
  value: VersionDictionary[Key]
}

function match<OtherProps, Key extends VersionKey, Result> (
  data: Partial<VersionDictionary>,
  handlers: Handlers<OtherProps, Result>,
  key: Key
): Matched<Key, OtherProps, Result> | undefined {
  const value = data[key]
  if (value == null) return undefined
  const handler = handlers[key]
  return { handler, value }
}
function handle<OtherProps, Result> (
  dictionary: Partial<VersionDictionary>,
  handlers: Handlers<OtherProps, Result>,
  execute: <Key extends VersionKey> (props: {
    value: VersionDictionary[Key]
    handler: Handler<Key, OtherProps, Result>
  }) => Result
): Result {
  let key: VersionKey
  for (key in handlers) {
    const matched = match(dictionary, handlers, key)
    if (matched == null) continue
    return execute({ value: matched.value, handler: matched.handler })
  }
  throw new Error('Unknown key')
}

const alphaData = { alpha: 'hello' }
const betaData = { beta: 4 }

const labelers = {
  alpha: (props: { value: string, label: string }) => `${props.label}: ${props.value}`,
  beta: (props: { value: number, label: string }) => `${props.label} + 1: ${props.value + 1}`
}

const label = `Test (${new Date().toISOString()})`

// When the generics are explicitly defined, the callbacks are correctly guaranteed
// to receive a matching type for the itss value prop and the handler's value prop
handle<{ label: string }, string>(
  alphaData,
  labelers, // This argument correctly throws an error if the value prop types do not match the keys in the handlers object
  (props) => props.handler({ value: props.value, label })
)
handle<{ label: string }, string>(betaData, labelers, (props) => props.handler({ value: props.value, label }))

// Without explict generics, there is an error!
// How can I infer the type of OtherProps and Result from the handlers?
handle(alphaData, labelers, (props) => {
  // I want this to know that the type of props.value will match the type of the value prop in the handler
  return props.handler({
    value: props.value, // Type 'VersionDictionary[Key]' is not assignable to type 'string & VersionDictionary[Key]'.
    // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string & VersionDictionary[Key]'.
    //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & VersionDictionary[Key]'.
    //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'VersionDictionary[Key]'.
    //       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    //         Type 'VersionDictionary[Key]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    //           Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    //             Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
    label
  })
})

const multipliers = {
  alpha: (props: { value: string, count: number }) => props.value.repeat(props.count),
  beta: (props: { value: number, count: number }) => props.value * props.count
}
const count = 5
// With explicit generics, no error
handle<{ count: number }, string | number>(alphaData, multipliers, (props) => props.handler({ value: props.value, count }))
// Without explicit generics, there are multiple errors:
handle(
  betaData,
  multipliers, // Argument of type '{ alpha: (props: { value: string; count: number;}) => string; beta: (props: { value: number; count: number;}) => number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Handlers<{ value: string; count: number; }, string>'.
  // The types returned by 'beta(...)' are incompatible between these types.
  //  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  (props) => {
    return props.handler({
      value: props.value, // // Type 'VersionDictionary[Key]' is not assignable to type 'string & VersionDictionary[Key]'.
      // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string & VersionDictionary[Key]'.
      //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & VersionDictionary[Key]'.
      //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'VersionDictionary[Key]'.
      //       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
      //         Type 'VersionDictionary[Key]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      //           Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      //             Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
      count
    })
  }
)


This is just unfortunate inference, I think. Inferring OtherProps from handlers is going to give you value in there. What you want to do is something like Omit<OtherProps, "value"> but then inference breaks entirely. I think the only way to make callers happy (not implementer) is something like this playground link where you infer from handlers. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz In that version the type of the handler value props are not typed to align with the type of the data in the VersionMap. If you switch the keys on lines 32 and 33, there is no error on line 39, even though the value props would be of the wrong type for that version. In the code I posted, there would correctly be an error as show in this playground link

Yes, that's just a side effect of using any. There are any number of ways to avoid that, such as using a recursive constraint as shown here. Does that meet your needs or am I still missing something?

@jcalz This works perfectly for the code as posted, but I cannot get it to work when inputs and result are generic as shown here. Do you know a solution? Should I edit the post or make a new post?

You’ll never be able to manipulate generic functions like that at the type level; I doubt it’s solvable if you make that a requirement (but I haven’t looked in an IDE yet). I would prefer you make a new post for it since the scope is expanding, but it’s up to you.

@jcalz I would accept an answer explaining the solution for this version, and I can make another post for the additional situation.

Okay. When you do that you might want to make that a [mre] that doesn't even involve the complexity of alpha and beta, because even simpler higher-order generics are very tough if not impossible to ask TS to infer.

When you try to infer a generic type argument for OtherProps from a value in handlers ultimately of the intersection type OtherProps & { value: VersionDictionary[Key] }, TypeScript will simply infer OtherProps as having a value property as well. It doesn't try to perform surgery on intersections to Omit pieces it doesn't care about. But having value inside OtherProps ruins the rest of your code. And if you start using Omit<OtherProps, "value"> in your types, then inference breaks completely (see microsoft/TypeScript#46748). This is simply a design limitation of TypeScript.

If you want better inference, I think you'll need to make the function generic in the entire type of handlers, and then from that compute the OtherProps and Result types, possibly as shown here (where I've replaced Key with K, OtherProps with T, and Result with R, for brevity):
type TfromH<H extends Handlers<any, any>> =
    H extends Handlers<infer T, any> ? Omit<T, "value"> : never;

type RfromH<H extends Handlers<any, any>> =
    H extends Handlers<any, infer R> ? R : never;

declare function handle<H extends Handlers<TfromH<H>, RfromH<H>>>(
    dictionary: Partial<VersionDictionary>,
    handlers: H,
    execute: <K extends VersionKey> (props: {
        value: VersionDictionary[K]
        handler: Handler<K, TfromH<H>, RfromH<H>>
    }) => RfromH<H>
): RfromH<H>

Here TfromH and RfromH can be used to infer T (aka OtherProps) and R (aka Result) from H of type Handlers<T, R>. Note that I've put Omit in there explicitly, so that when you infer T from H, the value property isn't in there to ruin things.
Note that H is constrained to Handlers<TfromH<H>, RfromH<H>>, which is a circular constraint that TS happens to allow. Essentially we're just saying that we want H to be a Handlers<T, R> type for some T and R, but there's no way to say "some" generic in TypeScript (that would involve existential types as requested in ms/TS# and discussed elsewhere, like Abstracting away a generic type parameter in typescript). Personally I would tend to write Handlers<any, any> there, but if that doesn't suffice, the recursive constraint should hopefully work.
Anyway, let's try it:
handle(alphaData, labelers, (props) => {
    /* (parameter) props: {
      value: VersionDictionary[K];
      handler: Handler<K, Omit<{
        value: string;
        label: string;
      } & {
        value: number;
        label: string;
      }, "value">, string>;
    } */

    return props.handler({
        value: props.value,
        //^? (property) value: VersionDictionary[K]
        label
        //^? (property) label: string
    })
})

That handler type is complicated looking, but if you put that Omit<⋯, "value"> into IntelliSense it will output {label: string}, which is what you wanted, and therefore value is of type VersionDictionary[K] and label is of type  string. Similarly:
handle(
    betaData,
    multipliers,
    (props) => {
        return props.handler({
            value: props.value,
            //^? (property) value: VersionDictionary[K]
            count
            //^? (property) count: number
        })
    }
)

That also works as expected, where value is of type VersionDictionary[K] and count is of type number.

So that works for the examples given here. It's possible that Omitting from an intersection with conflicting properties might not always work for you, and you'll have to do some other inference trick, but the whole approach is to start with the type of handlers and compute your other type arguments from them, because the default inference behavior for intersections will not behave the way you want.
Playground link to code
